# @Grape in scripts with multiple files

Tags: groovy

I'd like to use @Grape in my groovy program but my program consists of several files. The examples on the [Groovy Grape page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grapes+and+grab()) all seem to assume that your script will consist of one file. How can I do this? Should I just add it to one of the files and expect that the imports will work from the others? If so, then is it common to place all the @Grape calls in one file with no other code? Do I need to add the Grape call to all files that will import the package? Do I need to download the JAR and create a Gradle file, which I was getting away without at this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the grape engine and the @grab annotation were created as part of core groovy with single file scripts in mind, to allow a chunk of text to easily become a fully functional program.

for larger applications, gradle is an awesome build tool with lots of useful features.

but yes, you can manage all the application dependencies just with grape.
whether you annotate every file or a single one does not matter, just make sure the @grab annotated file is read before you try to use the external class.
annotating the main class is probably better as you will easily lose track of library versions if you have the annotations scattered.

and yes, you *should* consider gradle for any application with more than a dozen files or anything you might want to reuse elsewhere as a library.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it depends how your program is to be run...

If your program is to be run as a collection of standalone scripts, then I'd probably stick the `@Grab` required for each script at the top of each of them.

If your program is more of a *standard* style program with a single point of entry, then I'd go for using a build tool like Gradle (as you say), as you get a lot of easy wins by using it.

Firstly, it makes it easy to define your dependencies (and [build a single large jar](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GRADLE/Cookbook#Cookbook-Creatingafatjar) containing all of them)

Secondly, Gradle makes it really easy to start writing tests, include code coverage plugins, or useful tools [like codenarc](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/01/gradle-goodness-dont-let-codenarc.html) to suggest possible fixes or improvements to your code.  These all become invaluable not only for improving your code (or knowing your code works), but also when refactoring your code, you know you've not broken anything that used to work.

Comment: The question was about what I need to do, not what is appropriate. I think both of these options will work but are they the only options? Can I put the @Grape call in one place without using Gradle?